# C++ Save output of service in runtime

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I would like to collect output of service.exe to my c++ program (windows environment). In simple case there is call in cmd like "service.exe > log.txt" but in my case service is always shutdown by other system call "taskkill service.exe" that cause lack of output in log.txt.
How can I solve this ? I try windows _popen but the same as simple system function call - lack of output in file.

Code for example:

```
void test_of_runtime()
{
std::string result;

/* Create path to service */
boost::filesystem::path work_path(boost::filesystem::current_path());

/* Run servie and save output in log file */
work_path += "\\service.exe > runtime_log.txt";

/* Create another thread which terminate service after 10 seconds */
boost::thread terminate_thread(terminate_thread_func);
terminate_thread.detach();

system(work_path.string().c_str());
}



void terminate_thread_func()
{
std::string terminate_command = "taskkill /F /T /IM service.exe";

/* Wait 10 sec */
boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::seconds(10));

/* Terminate service after 10 sec */
system(terminate_command.c_str());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid terminating any task with `taskkill /f` except in exceptionnal conditions. The correct way is to send a *signal* to the running task that it should stop to allow it to eventually do some cleanup and flush its buffers.

If `service.exe` has a message loop, you can use `PostThreadMessage`, provided you have access to the id of the thread using the message queue. You normally get it in the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure filled by the `CreateProcess` call.

If `service.exe` has not message loop (i.e. it is written as a *console* application), it could register a `HandlerRoutine` with `SetConsoleCtrlHandler`. You could then send a `CTRL_BREAK_EVENT` with the [`GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683155.aspx) function or with `taskkill` **without `/F`** (still unsure about this last one). You will find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16826362/3545273) an usage example of a *break handler*.

If none of above is an option, them `service.exe` must be ready to be forcibly killed at any time. That means it should not buffer its output, and specifically you should not start it with `service.exe > log.txt` and have it write to stdout, but instead give it the name of a log file, and the program should ideally log using the open write close pattern.