# How do I run certain code/function before the program exits in D?

Tags: d, exit, exit-code

Suppose I have loop which awaits for user input. If user presses Ctrl+C the program exits normally. However, I'd like to do a couple of things before exit. Is it possible to run a function once Ctrl+C was pressed and program is about to exit?

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? (or whatever)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `core.stdc.signal`, which contains bindings to the C header `signal.h`. Now, if this is for Windows, you might run into some [problems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx):

> SIGINT is not supported for any Win32 application. When a 
>   CTRL+Cinterrupt occurs, Win32 operating systems generate a new thread to 
>   specifically handle that interrupt. This can cause a single-thread 
>   application, such as one in UNIX, to become multithreaded and cause 
>   unexpected behavior.

```d
__gshared bool running = true;
extern(C) void handleInterrupt(int) nothrow @nogc
{
    running = false;
}

void main()
{
    import core.stdc.signal;
    signal(SIGINT, &handleInterrupt);

    scope(exit)
    {
        //Cleanup
        import std.stdio : writeln;
        writeln("Done");
    }

    while(running)
    {
        //Do some work
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826097/equivalent-to-sigint-posix-signal-for-catching-ctrlc-under-windows-mingw shows how to do it on Windows. Good answer btw!

Answer (score 1):

You could probably get away with something like this:

```d
void main() {
    try {
        dostuff();
    } finally {
        printf("bye\n");
    };
};
```

The finally block will run even if the `dostuff()` throws an `Error` or `Throwable`. I'm not very familiar with standard-IO, console signals, or whatever, but give this a try at least.

Furthermore, even if `dostuff()` calls `Runtime.terminate()` the finally block will still run. The same cannot be said for `abort()` though.

Comment: that won't do it on Linux though, ctrl+c by default bypasses the exception mechanism.