How to send Ctrl+C to boost::process?
I launch FFmpeg in boost::process and get data from it every n seconds.
If I terminate the app or FFmpeg in the console using Ctrl+C, FFmpeg flushes all data it has to stdout.
But, if I terminate boost::process using the terminate() function, I don't get any data flushed. So I need to send Ctrl+C signal to the process before terminating it to get flushed data from FFmpeg.
I tried:
GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, c.id())

But, it seems to have no effect.

What platform? Probably Windows since you used GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent

I would try TerminateProcess(c.native_handle(), 0);

I resolve by using https://stackoverflow.com/a/16826362/10147477
SetConsoleCtrlHandler and using GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, c.id())
. So ffmpeg get ctrl-c and i can add logic to handle ctrl-c signal inside my app
